# Symfony2 locale not persisted on AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have one custom LocaleListner who persist choosed locale on database:

```
class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    private $securityContext;

    private $em;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale, SecurityContext $securityContext, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(
                array('onKernelRequest', -50)
            ),
        );
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        // Impersonate account check
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        $user = null;
        if ($this->securityContext->getToken()) {
            $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
        }

        if ($locale = $request->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
            if (null !== $user && $user != 'anon.' && $user->getLocale() !== $locale) {
                $user->setLocale($locale);
                $this->em->persist($user);
                $this->em->flush();
            }
        } else if ($user instanceof User && null !== $user->getLocale()) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        }

        $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
    }
}
```

This works perfectly but the locale is totally ignored if I call a controller with an **AJAX request**.

Indeed, the default locale is fr. And if I choose the en locale and made ajax request, the returned template is translated to french, not english.

How this is possible?

Thanks.

EDIT.

Here my javascript ajax call (coffee):

```
refreshUrl = Routing.generate('ticket_index') + location.search
setInterval =>
  $.get refreshUrl, { _ajax: 1 }, (data) =>
    @tbody.html data
    momentFromNow()
, 10000
```

I already try to add _locale parameter on ajax request, don't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found why this not works.

The chosen priority cause this issue, changed `-50` to `17` solve everything.

But I don't understand at all why the priority influence to the translations on AJAX requests...

If somebody has an explanation, I'm hearing! ;)

Thanks [Alexandru Olaru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4477818/alexandru-olaru) for help.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very nice to post the ajax request i am guessing the problem could come from data that you are sending within ajax.

```
$.ajax({
   url: path_to_your_controller,
   data: {'_locale': 'en'} //you probably are missing this part
})
```

Comment: Updated my post.
I already try to add _locale parameter on ajax request, don't works.

Comment: What i noticed in your code is the line:

 KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(
                array('onKernelRequest', -50)
            ),
Usually in documentation and on symfony 2  book they use 18 instead of -50. I guess you should experiment with this number.

Comment: Is not 18 the value of the default local listener?

Comment: Yep Default locale is 18, I use 17 for The my Sticky Locale code.